# GHDL script to analyze, elaborate, run, and dump a vcd file with vhdl-2008?

Tags: vhdl

GHDL documentation basically says you need to do the following to analyze, elaborate, and run your simulation:

```
ghdl -a --std=08 --ieee=synopsys --work=work mytop.vhdl 
ghdl --elab-run --std=08 --ieee=synopsys mytop
```

However, --vcd flag doesn't appear to work with --elab-run flag, so I was wondering how to go about dumping the vcd file with the elab-run flag.  (or if there's a work around for this issue)

```
ghdl.exe --elab-run --std=08 --ieee=synopsys --vcd=waves.vcd mytop
ERROR: ghdl.exe: unknown option '--vcd=waves.vcd' for command '--elab-run'
```

Comment: [Invoking GHDL](https://ghdl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using/InvokingGHDL.html#elaborate-and-run-elab-run) in the on-line documentation shows run_options after the design unit. The command line help (here `ghdl.exe --help --elab-run`) shows `--elab-run [OPTS] UNIT [ARCH] [OPTS]` where you're left guessing which options go where (and the runtime options aren't shown). The run_options are shown in [Simulation options](https://ghdl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using/Simulation.html#simulation-options). Disjunct command line help and documentation.  File an [issue?](https://github.com/ghdl/ghdl/issues)

Answer (score 0):

This is what I found out by trial and error...GHDL requires the simulation options after the toplevel name and the elaboration argument before it and after "--elab-run".

```
ghdl -a --std=08 --ieee=synopsys --work=work mytop.vhdl 
ghdl --elab-run --std=08 --ieee=synopsys mytop --vcd=waves.vcd --ieee-asserts=disable
```

the above works without error.